# OpenLayers and MapServer: GetFeatureInfo and JSON

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I'm using OpenLayers 2.0 and MapServer.

I would query MapServer and I would that it return to me a JSON file:

On my page, I generated dynamic URL as:

```
MAP/MAP.map&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=TANK&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=15.256938,38.195583,15.293846,38.210523&WIDTH=1720&HEIGHT=886&QUERY_LAYERS=TANK&INFO_FORMAT=text/plain&X=762&Y=685
```

In the file MAP.map (my Mapserver) I defined:

METADATA section:

```
  "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/plain"
  "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
  "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "application/json"
  "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "application/vnd.ogc.gml"
  "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "gml"
```

LAYER section: 
       HEADER   "/template/header.ftl"

```
[
```

TEMPLATE "/template/content.ftl"

```
{
    id: [TANK_ID],
    attribute: [DESCRIPTION]
}
```

FOOTER   "/template/footer.ftl"

```
]
```

If I launch the URL in my browser:

```
GetFeatureInfo results:

Layer 'TANK'
  Feature 100:
```

If I convert INFO_FORMAT in text/html, it works fine.

Why?

Comment: You ask for INFO_FORMAT=text/plain and you receive plain text which is expected result.

Comment: Ok, in the case, what is the correct format?
I tried with info_format=application/json, but the server generated this error:
msWMSFeatureInfo(): WMS server error. Unsupported INFO_FORMAT value (info_format=application/json).

Comment: You can have only one "wms_feature_info_mime_type" in metadata. For a list you should probably use "wms_getfeatureinfo_formatlist". Checking GetCapabilities is, as always with WMS, the first thing to do. Does is list application/json as supported info format? Before your desired format is listed it is wasting your time to do anything else.

Comment: I use GetCapabilities:
    `<GetFeatureInfo>
      <Format>application/json</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
      <Format>text/plain</Format>
      <DCPType>
        <HTTP>
          <Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://vertigo-w7:8080/fcgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/ms4w/apps/RAM/RAM.map&amp;"/></Get>
          <Post><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://vertigo-w7:8080/fcgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=c:/ms4w/apps/RAM/RAM.map&amp;"/></Post>
        </HTTP>
      </DCPType>
    </GetFeatureInfo>`

Comment: Ok, that means that info_format=application/json should be supported. How have you defined the corresponding outputformat? See example from http://mapserver.org/output/template_output.html.